# Java android - private constructor in a static class doesn't get called

Tags: java, android, static, singleton

I am using the static class that you can find here below,
but from some reason when I am using the class getEmail(){... method I get exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.techsolutions.appgrade/com.techsolutions.appgrade.View.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.content.SharedPreferences.contains(java.lang.String)' **on a null object reference**

It looks like the private constructor doesn't get called.

**This is my static class:**

```
package com.techsolutions.appgrade.Logic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.EmailValidator;

public final class DataController extends Application{

    private static SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private static Context context;

    private static boolean isRegistered;

    private static String PREF_NAME = "StudentSharedPref";
    private static String KEY_Name = "name";
    private static String KEY_Email = "email";
    private static String KEY_PhoneNum = "phoneNum";
    private static String KEY_Age = "age";
    private static String KEY_Realm = "age";

    public static DataController instance;

    private DataController()
    {
        System.out.println("Been HERE");
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPref.edit();
        context = getApplicationContext();

        isRegistered = false;
    }

    public static void setName(String name)
    {
        editor.putString(KEY_Name, name);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String getName(){
        if(sharedPref.contains(KEY_Name))
        {
            return sharedPref.getString(KEY_Name, "");
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static boolean setEmail(String email)
    {
        if(!EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(email))
            return false;

        editor.putString(KEY_Email, email);
        editor.apply();
        return true;
    }

    public static String getEmail(){
        if(sharedPref.contains(KEY_Email))
        {
            return sharedPref.getString(KEY_Email, "");
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static boolean setPhonNum(String phoneNum)
    {
        if(String.valueOf(phoneNum).length() == 10)
            return false;

        editor.putString(KEY_PhoneNum, phoneNum);
        editor.apply();
        return true;
    }

    public static String getPhoneNum(){
        if(sharedPref.contains(KEY_PhoneNum))
        {
            return sharedPref.getString(KEY_PhoneNum, "");
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static boolean setAge(int age)
    {
        if(age <= 0 || age>120)
            return false;

        editor.putInt(KEY_Age, age);
        editor.apply();
        return true;

    }

    public static String getAge(){
        if(sharedPref.contains(KEY_Age))
        {
            return sharedPref.getString(KEY_Age, "");
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static void setRealm(String realm)
    {
        editor.putString(KEY_Realm, realm);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String getRealm(){
        if(sharedPref.contains(KEY_Realm))
        {
            return sharedPref.getString(KEY_Realm, "");
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

**and this is how I called the method from another class:**

```
DataController.setEmail(email)
```

Comment: There is no static class shown in the example.

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling your constructor. Your constructor is private. It can't be called from outside your class. You are trying to create a singleton. You forgot your newInstance method in your singleton.

```
public static DataController newInstance(){
   if(instance == nul){
      instance = new DataController();
   }
   return instance;
}
```

After this you can call

```
DataController dataController = DataController.newInstance();
```

to initialize your class, or get an existing instance of your class.

Also i wouldn't recommend extending your application class in this case, just because you need to able to acces the context.
You can add a Context variable which you can set after you have called the newInstance method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static DataController instance;
```

Do you need to initialise a static class?